# Calling a javascript function out of java

Tags: java, javascript, vaadin, jsni, jsobject

Im trying to call a javascript function out of my Vaadin Portlet.

lets say I have an HTML file witch is located in my project ;

homepage.html

```
<html>  
   ...  
   <script type="text/javascript">  
   ...  
   function foo(String msg)   
   {  
      alert(msg);  
   }  
   ...  
  </script>  
   ...  
</html>
```

the page in Embedded in my Portlet via the [Vaadin Embedded Browser](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#WebEmbed)

how do I call the function foo(String msg) out of my java application

do i need to import/read the homepage.html file and just call it or is it something else I have to do ?

Comment: Is your Java application an applet on the same page?

Comment: @Thilo its a bit more , Its an Portlet that has an Embeded browser , the Browser actualy loads the html page

Comment: A portlet with an embedded browser? You mean an iframe (loaded by the browser that accesses the portlet)?

Comment: @Thilo take a look at this , http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#WebEmbed  you can view the source code too

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere. Adding a Vaadin tag.

Answer (score 1):

firstly you need to get the script body;
then you can user `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager` to solve your problem [javax.script.*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html)
pseudo code

```
import javax.script.*;
ScriptEngine engine = 
            new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
String script = getScript(path_to_html);
            engine.eval(script);
```

Comment: And then there is the problem of what to do when the script tries to interact with what it presumably thinks is the web browser that hosts the HTML it is embedded it. Notice that the sample script says `alert()`. What is that supposed to do in this context?

Comment: if your application is applet ,you can parse the script and eval in current context,if your application is desktop application you may need to embed a webbrowser and if your application is web project,just include the page or get script then write to your page

Comment: Apparently it is a Vaadin portlet using their WebEmbed component: http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#WebEmbed (which I guess is an iframe).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to include an external javascript file into a Vaadin application is to override the `Application#writeAjaxPageHtmlVaadinScripts` method.

To call a javascript function from the Vaadin server-side code, you call `Window#executeJavascript`

```
@Override
protected void writeAjaxPageHtmlVaadinScripts(Window window,
                                              String themeName, Application application, BufferedWriter page,
                                              String appUrl, String themeUri, String appId,
                                              HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {
  page.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n");
  page.write("//<![CDATA[\n");
  page.write("document.write(\"<script language='javascript' src='" + appUrl + "/VAADIN/scripts/example.js'><\\/script>\");\n");
  page.write("//]]>\n</script>\n");
  super.writeAjaxPageHtmlVaadinScripts(window, themeName, application,
      page, appUrl, themeUri, appId, request);
}
```

NB : I have never used Vaadin as a Portlet, but a quick look suggests that this should work OK.

However, this approach is rather rudimentary, and only suitable for a quick hack/proof-of-concept: if you want to so anything more sophisticated, then developing your own Vaadin widget is correct approach. It gives you the power of GWT and JSNI, and gives you a much finer grain of control : See [The Book Of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to following links, these provides API for doing what you want to do,

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things9/index.html

http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/execute-javascript-from-java/